# Compare two std::list lists and get different objects

Tags: c++, compare, stdlist

Is there ready function to get difference of two `std::list` lists?

For example I have `list1: obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4` and `list2: obj2, obj3, obj4, obj5`.

The function result should be `list1_unique: obj1`, `list1_and_list2: obj2, obj3, obj4`, `list2_unique: obj5`.

(It's not hard to write my own implementation but I would prefer standard function)

Comment: You should probably be using sets, not lists.

Comment: Using lists is preferred because I frequently add/remove elements (keeping list sorted manually). `Set` may be less effective because of it's 'autosorting'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your lists are sorted (as your examples appear to be), [`std::set_difference`](http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibref/set-difference.html) to get `list1_unique` and `list2_unique`, and [`std::set_intersection`](http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibref/set-intersection.html) to get `list1_and_list2`. If they're not already sorted, you could sort them with `std::list::sort()`.

Comment: The lists are ordered and I can define comparison function which represents that order. Thanks for answer!

Comment: @JohnDibling Deserves 2 for being treated that way by the OP ;) (assuming you gave the one up-vote). I never understood people not up-voting an answer they found at least that good to accept it, but well.

Comment: @brigadir: If you use your own comparison function to sort the lists, be sure to pass that to the set algorithms you use as well.